# Find all real triplets (x,y,z) (German Math Olympiad 2018 Q2, 2nd Round)

Tags: contest-math, systems-of-equations

Find all real triplets $(x,y,z)$ such that

$\begin{alignat*}{3}
x^2 &+ y &&+ z &&&= q \; \; (1) \\
x \; &+ y^2 &&+ z &&&= q \; \; (2)\\
x \;  &+ y &&+ z^2 \; &&&= q \; \; (3)
\end{alignat*}$

where $q=\dfrac{5}{4}$

Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$ and applying the difference of squares, I get:

$x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)= x-y \implies x+y = 1 \; \; (4)$

Substituting $(4)$ in $(3)$, I get $x=\dfrac{1}{2} = y = z$ due to symmetry.

Is this the only triplet or did I miss something?

And when $q=-1$ there should be no real triplets, right?

Comment: what if $x=y$, u can't divide by zero

Comment: Hmm, that's right. But I'm wondering since $x=y=z=\dfrac{1}{2}$ works for $q=\dfrac{5}{4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $z$ from the first equation we obtain
$$
(x-y)(x+y-1)=0
$$
from the second equation. By the third equation, we obtain the solutions
$$
(x,y,z)=(-1/2,3/2,-1/2), (-1/2,-1/2,3/2),(-5/2,-5/2,-5/2),(3/2,-1/2,-1/2),(1/2,1/2,1/2).
$$
For $q=-1$, we obtain $(x + y - 1)(x - y)=0$ and then
$(x,y,z)=(-1,-1,-1)$ is the only real solution.
We have more complex solutions, like $(x,y,z)=(1-\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-2})$ for example.

Comment: Thank you, but how exactly did you obtain the solutions by the third equation?

Comment: Consider two cases. First, $x=y$. Then the third equation gives $(2x + 5)(2x + 1)(2x - 1)=0$. Similar the case $x\neq y$, where we have $y=1-x$.

Comment: If $q = -1$ then $(-1, -1, -1)$ is the only real solution.

Comment: @DietrichBurde how did you get $(2x+5)(2x+1)(2x-1) = 0$

Comment: As I said. Compute the third equation with $z=-(x^2+y-q)$ and $y=x$. Then you obtain $0=16x^4 + 32x^3 - 24x^2 - 8x + 5=(2x+5)(2x+1)(2x-1)$